# creating a link in <XSL: stylesheet with more than one GET variable

Tags: php, xslt

I am creating links in an XSL stylesheet but it will not accept '&' only '& a m p;' (I had to put spaces between the characters so that this CMS would not convert it to its equivalent &) so my links look like href="home.com?first=GET1& a m p;second=GET2" instead of  href="home.com?first=GET1&second=GET2" but when php recieves the variable the '&' is split and my second variable becomes [amp;second]=>GET2. Can you please help me to address this problem?

Comment: That shouldn't really be an issue; even if you create a link with `first=GET1&amp;second=GET2` in it, most browsers will collapse the `&amp;` down when the user clicks on the link. Certainly Firefox and IE do, I haven't tried them all. How exactly are the links being followed?

Answer (score 0):

**You must use** `&amp;name=value`.

`&amp;` is just the way an ampersand must be specified in any XML document -- it is still just an ampersand.

**Example**:

```
<a href="http://www.some.come/x.html?x=1&amp;y=2&amp;z=3">A Link </a>
```

Comment: that is what I used but the &amp; is not rendered and it gets passed to PHP which uses the & and considers the amp; as part of the second variable

Comment: You must be doing something wrong in your PHP program. For more than three years nobody else have complained of a similar problem. To test that the link is generated correctly, use a real link, get the output of the XSLT transformation and click on the link to verify that you get correct response.

Comment: I was trying to implement questions/3133761/image-src-from-php-script-on-iis-not-displaying-consistently from stackolerflow using two parameters. I do not know what I did wrong but I did it over using the same structure above and it works